# How to force PHP to ignore daylight saving time?

Tags: php, timezone, dst

I have some web applications running on PHP 7.4.26 on a Windows server. This year (2023) Mexican goverment decided to stop using Daylight saving time (DST) and is causing me a problem.
My web apps require to use America/Mexico_City timezone but PHP keeps using DST, adding an undessired extra hour.
I was able to change the windows server time to ignore DST. Therefore, the server has the right time. But PHP keeps giving the wrong one.
I cannot modify the server to have one hour less (as a workaround), because it is used for other non PHP applications.
How can I force PHP to ignore DST, so I can keep using the right timezone?
Thank you very much.

Comment: PHP gets its DST rules from the operating system. You need to update the server's timezone information to match the change in the law.

Comment: @Barmar: The OP says that the server has already been changed, which suggests that it's *not* using the OS for the time zone data. Perhaps the [timezonedb](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) package is being used? If so, I'd suggest just updating that...

Comment: Did you changed timezone in PHP.ini? Are you using any framework which can have its own datetime settings?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you won't be able to get that timezone DST change without upgrading to PHP 8+.

PHP includes a copy of the [IANA Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) and [periodically updates it with newer versions of PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src/commits/master/ext/date/lib/timezonedb.h).

As you can see in the IANA mailing list, the changes for [Mexico's removal of DST changes were not added until version 2022e in October 2022](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2022-October/000074.html).

As [this 3v4l shows](https://3v4l.org/VOg7U) that no version of PHP 7 comes bundled with the timezone database the includes the changes in Mexico. You need a minimum version of 8.0.26, 8.1.13, or 8.2. Since PHP 7 is already EOL and no longer receiving any updates, it's a great time to upgrade.

Comment: You don't necessarily _have_ to update PHP [though _all versions of PHP7 are currently EOL_, so you _should_ update] to get the new timezone data. A mentioned in the comments you can get the optional [`timezonedb`](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) extension which overlays the updates. This may be provided through your distro's package manager, or otherwise via PECL.